# How to create json structure from list of data?

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, asp.net-web-api

I want to create json structure with nested object from my list object.

This is my class:

```
public class Employee
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public int Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
     public List<int> Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

Records are like this:

```
EmployeeId   SkillssetPoints   Date
 1              10             4/5/2016 16:12:12
 2              12             3/5/2016 17:12:12
 3              4              8/5/2016 8:12:12
 4              20             1/5/2016 2:12:12
```

This is how i am getting data:

```
var data=context.Employee.Tolist();
```

After getting data i want to create this **json structure** from above data using `EmployeeModel` and return:

**Expected Output:**

```
 {"Date":"8-5-2016 08:12:12","SkillssetPoints":[4,10,12,20]}
```

In Date field i would take Highest date so `8-5-2016` and **SkillssetPoints** will be order by ascending.

How to create this json structure with my **EmployeeModel** class??

Comment: you  should state clearly that you only want 1 record returned and you would like someone to tell you how to filter your Employee list list so it only shows the "highest date"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a reference to the nuget package Newtonsoft.Json then use ...

```
string result = JsonConvert.Serialize(data);
```

It looks like you need to translate the data in your db to the model format by doing a projection first then serialize the result ...

```
var groupedData = data
    .GroupBy(s => s.EmployeeId)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Date)
    .Select(g => new EmployeeModel {
        EmployeeId = g.Key,
        Name = g.First().Name,
        Date = g.First().Date,
        Skillssetpoints = g.Select(s => s.Skillssetpoints).OrderBy(i => i).ToList()
    });
```

That should produce a collection of this model ...

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<int> Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
}
```

... when I do this ...

```
var data = new List<EmployeeModel> {
    new EmployeeModel { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "Homer Simpson", Skillssetpoints = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 }, Date = DateTime.Now },
    new EmployeeModel { EmployeeId = 2, Name = "Marge Simpson", Skillssetpoints = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 }, Date = DateTime.Now },
    new EmployeeModel { EmployeeId = 3, Name = "Lisa Simpson", Skillssetpoints = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 }, Date = DateTime.Now },
    new EmployeeModel { EmployeeId = 4, Name = "Bart Simpson", Skillssetpoints = new List<int> { 1,2,3,4 }, Date = DateTime.Now }
};

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
```

I get this output ...

```
[
    {
        "EmployeeId": 1,
        "Skillssetpoints": [1,2,3,4],
        "Name": "Homer Simpson",
        "Date": "2016-04-05T11:42:09.9126748+01:00"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": 2,
        "Skillssetpoints": [1,2,3,4],
        "Name": "Marge Simpson",
        "Date": "2016-04-05T11:42:09.9126748+01:00"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": 3,
        "Skillssetpoints": [1,2,3,4],
        "Name": "Lisa Simpson",
        "Date": "2016-04-05T11:42:09.9126748+01:00"
    },
    {
        "EmployeeId": 4,
        "Skillssetpoints": [1,2,3,4],
        "Name": "Bart Simpson",
        "Date": "2016-04-05T11:42:09.9126748+01:00"
    }
]
```

Comment: Please see my question as using your solution is giving me output like this:[{},{}]

Answer (score 2):

Select your required records by grouping on particular field and then prepare the anonymous object in required pattern and serialize it for final results,

```
        var models = (from em in employeeModels
                      group em by em.ID into g
                      select new
                      {
                          Id = g.Key,
                          maxDate = g.Max(p => p.Date)
                      }).ToList();
        var result = new
        {
            date = prices.Max(p => p.maxDate),
            SkillssetPoints = prices.Select(p => p.Id).ToList()
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

You will get the json in the pattern like

```
{
    "date": "2016-04-05T16:39:54.8420979+05:30",
    "SkillssetPoints": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try to create a new object and serialize as below:

```
var result = JsonConvert.Serialize (new {
    Date = context.Employee.Max(e => e.Date),
    SkillssetPoints = context.Employee.Select(e => e.SkillssetPoints)
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use newton JSON,it is available on NuGet and code is extremely easy.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var jsonList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Employee.Tolist());
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Use Newton JSON from Nuget Package and try This code

List lstEmp = new List();

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.EmployeeId = i;
            emp.Name = "Name" + i;
            emp.Skillssetpoints = i + 1;
            emp.Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
            lstEmp.Add(emp);
        }

        var data = lstEmp;
        var result = new EmployeeModel
        {
            Date = data.Max(p => p.Date),
            Skillssetpoints = data.Select(p => p.Skillssetpoints).ToList()
        };

        var JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
        {
            Date = result.Date,
            Skillssetpoints = result.Skillssetpoints
        });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

1) Install Newtonsoft.Json package using NuGet

2) add namespace on top

```
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

3) Add [JsonIgnore] on top of Model class properties which you don't want to include in json conversion

```
 public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeModel
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public List<int> Skillssetpoints { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
}
```

4) Final code is below

```
var data = new List<Employee>();
        data.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 1, Skillssetpoints = 10, Date = Convert.ToDateTime("4/5/2016 16:12:12") });
        data.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 2, Skillssetpoints = 12, Date = Convert.ToDateTime("3/5/2016 17:12:12") });
        data.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 3, Skillssetpoints = 4, Date = Convert.ToDateTime("8/5/2016 8:12:12") });
        data.Add(new Employee { EmployeeId = 4, Skillssetpoints = 20, Date = Convert.ToDateTime("1/5/2016 2:12:12") });

        var highestDate = data.OrderByDescending(e => e.Date).First().Date;
        var skillssetpointsList = data.Select(e => e.Skillssetpoints).ToList();


        EmployeeModel employeeModel = new EmployeeModel()
        {
            Date = highestDate,
            Skillssetpoints = skillssetpointsList
        };

        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(employeeModel);
```

Now, jsonString = {"Skillssetpoints":[10,12,4,20],"Date":"2016-05-08T08:12:12"}

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this
it works fine with me.

```
public ActionResult GetCitiesWithBranches(int regionID)
    {
        var cities =
            _context.Cities.Where(e => e.RegionCode == regionID)
                .Select(e => new { ID = e.CityCode, Name = e.Name })
                .ToList();
        return Json(new { cities = cities });
    }
```

and in the view i am using that:

```
var json = { regionID: data };
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCitiesWithBranches", "Admin")',
            data: json,
            dataType: "json",
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                //alert("error routine");
            },
            success: function (res) {                    
                if (res.cities) {

                }
            }
        });
```

Hope that will help..

Comment: Does this works in Web api controller:Json(new { cities = cities });

Comment: I didn't try it in web api controller.