# How to get flat list of property and its values in JSON from any kind of object structure (using recursive method?) in C#.Net core?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am building chunk of code(generic) which will return list of property and values from any structure of object (either list or single object or list within single object or single object within list or list within list or single object within object) in json based on input request.
Let me explain you the use case- I am getting list of properties in accordance with class name and I need to send back its values in json in list format.
For e.g. I am getting input request for following properties SPTeam.Name, SPRole.Name, SPTeam.AltName1, Client.Name and I want to process data retrieved from DB and send its values in list format in json like,

```
{ 
"SPTeam":[ 
 { 
   "Name": "AUBERT & DUVAL Development",
   "AltName1": "AUBERT & DUVAL Development",
   "SPRole" : [
   {
     "Name": "Charter Full Stack Developer II"
   },
   {
     "Name": "General Consulting Engineer"
   }]
},
{
  "Name": "SmartHands_Dedicated_Team",
  "AltName1": "SmartHands_Dedicated_TeamAltName1",
  "SPRole" : [
   {
     "Name": "Accountant"
   },
   {
     "Name": "Senior accountant"
   }]
}],
"Client" : [
{
"Name": "Davita Medical Group"
}
]}
```

The data model or the structure from which I need to get properties and values is-

```
Public class SPTeam
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string AltName1 { get; set; }
  public string AltName2 { get; set; }
  public List<SPRole> SPRole { get; set; }
}

Public class SPRole
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int AvgCostHr { get; set; }
  public int SellPriceHr { get; set; }
  public int GPPct { get; set; }
}

Public class Client
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }  
}
```

The data model or structure and its relationship with other classes is dynamic (not any fixed class) and I need to retrieve data only for specific properties maintaining association/relationships between them.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks,

Comment: Where does the recursion enter into the picture?

Comment: you want to post this JSON Data to server and you need a class structure to post this json ??  right ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil, I want to send JSON data to client who is requesting these fields in structured manner

Comment: @Charlie, went through various posts from stack overflow before posting my question, which suggest to create recursive function which will search for specific property through entire structure/hierarchy and get its value once found. But this approach will give me data for that property only. It doesn't give me data in the form of its relationship with other entities if it is present/asked in request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that a core portion of your question may be resolved by the following:

[How to create json structure from list of data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423598/how-to-create-json-structure-from-list-of-data)

However, in your case I'm not sure what level of generic capability you are requiring. You mention that "The data model or structure and its relationship with other classes is DYNAMIC (not any fixed class)" on the one hand, then you mention: "I need to retrieve data only for SPECIFIC PROPERTIES maintaining association/relationships between them".

What is the level of generic capability between, what seems to me, to be conflicting requirements? If you only want to retrieve specific properties, then where are you tracking the properties (and associated class structures) you want to retrieve?

I believe the answer you're looking for will depend on how you answer this.

Comment: i may be sorry for the confusion, but when I said "I need to retrieve data only for SPECIFIC PROPERTIES maintaining association/relationships between them" means, SPRole data model has many fields/properties like AvgCostHr,SellPriceHr,GPPct etc., but request ask data for Name only, though I have data associated to them too.
And in context with dynamic structure- in future request may contain fields or properties from any other data model and its associated members. Not necessary, we would get request associated to above three data models.

Comment: 1. What's the signature of the client call to you for information? For this request I'm making, please use your example in your question, where SPTeam contains a list of SPRole, and the client is requesting the "Name" of an SPRole.

2. Are you using a Data Access Layer in your architecture? Are you in a position to modify that layer if necessary?

3. I'm assuming that those classes you defined will be modified in the future if any changes are necessary. And new classes, for example, say, SPTeamMember, could be added?